# Add a line under the text when hover in css

Tags: html, css

I am building a menu and want to add a line under the text when i hover over the menu. The kind of line i want to add is like this [Image Link](http://s27.postimg.org/cwbx569f3/home.png)

Here is the CSS code:

```
nav {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

nav li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

nav a {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:5px 5px 5px 30px ;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #283744;
}

nav a:hover, nav a:active {

}
```

Comment: We'll need the HTML too. Could you provide a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

If you want the underline to be the same color as the text, otherwise you'll have to do

```
border-bottom: solid 1px green;
```

or whatever color you want

Comment: border-bottom seems to correspond better to what OP is looking for, and is better for positioning / size / etc ...

Comment: thanks dave actually i was using " text-decoration: underline; " but didn't know how to change the colour, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

```
nav a:hover, nav a:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

If it doesn't work, change `nav a` to `nav a:link`

Answer (score 0):

Add: `text-decoration: underline;`

Answer (score 0):

```
nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration